# How to encrypt a Windows Server hard-drive remotely?

Tags: disk-encryption, windows

I have a couple of dedicated servers running Windows 2012 on the other side of the country. My only access to these servers are through RDP.

For compliance reasons, I will need to encrypt their hard-drives. Is there a way to do that without physical access to the servers?

Comment: ...are they physical servers?  Virtualized in some way?  Co-located?

Comment: Physical servers. Not virtualized. I have no physical access to them though.

Comment: Do the machines have a TPM?  What about a remote KVM switch or console?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of methods to encrypt data disks, such as BitLocker, VeraCrypt and the like. But whatever method is used, you need to decrypt at startup if you turn it on for system drive, except BitLocker with TPM, which, I don't believe, is available.